# Typescript project setup

Tags: typescript

I am pretty new to Typescript and I having trouble starting the typescript project setup. Have done all the installations required and ran very simple programs and works perfect. Need help in setting up a project in a specific requirement.

Have a project structure like:

```
myProject
    -node_modules
    -src
        -controller
            -MyController.ts
        -service
            -MyService.ts
        -domain
            -MyDomain.ts
        -exception
            -MyException.ts
        -constants
            -MyConstant.ts
        app.ts
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
    yarn.lock
```

I need to run this project which should call `app.ts` first which will inturn call my controller and then my service to display *Hello World*.

What code will I write in `app.ts`, `MyController.ts` and `MyService.ts`?

I know this is a big ask. But I dont have a learning curve now to learn `ts`. Have to learn it on the go. Any sample project or code which help me pick pace soon.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

**UPDATE**:

*package.json*:

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/app.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.14",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --config nodemon.json src/app.ts",
    "start": "node src/app.js",
    "build": "tsc --myProject ."
  }
}
```

*tsconfig.json*:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",   
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "strict": true,  
    "skipLibCheck": true 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to create an Web API ? If yes you can use [NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/), it's a complete framework which offer you the possibility to create Web API in typescript on NodeJS Runtime. With it you will also be able to use dependency injection with typescript decorators.

I hope it will help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a exported class or method to be called. Place this in your MyController.ts file:

```
export class MyController {
    public static execute() {
        return 'MyController Hello World'
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from app.ts like this:

```
import { MyController } from './controller/MyController'

console.log(MyController.execute())
```

Comment: `PS D:\ReactWorkspaces\standardizer> npm start

> standardizer@1.0.0 start
> node src/app.js`
This is what I received when running `npm start`. Not showing the controller logs.

Comment: Might we see your package.json and your tsconfig.json? Did you do the "tsc" step?

Comment: Please check the update in question.

Comment: So yes, you were not getting any logs because we were not logging anything. I've updated the code in app.ts. Please, check it. Best,